# What are the limitations of the D, L system and the (+), (-) system for naming organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry, optical-properties

In organic chemistry, both the D, L system and the (+), (-) system are widely used, in conjunction with the modern (R, S) system.

The D, L system names an organic molecule based on the direction that its bottom -OH group points at, when the molecule is drawn with the most oxidized carbon on top in the Fischer projection. Is it true that organic molecules that cannot be drawn and analyzed in this way cannot be named according to this system? Also, is this system incapable of specifying diastereomers and epimers among stereoisomers, as it was first invented to address enantiomers?

As for the (+), (-) system, I think as long as an organic molecule does not have optical activity, it cannot be named in accordance with this system. Does this sound right?

Comment: Well many rules and terms are specific for a class. Actually is the aim, in a way. You won't use ciclo for a linear molecule. The +/- signs refers, on the other hand, to the actual optical activity.

Comment: +/− is only designed to work for chiral molecules. Saying that it can't work with achiral molecules is true, but pointless, because it was never meant to do so. A bigger problem is that the sign of optical rotation tells you nothing about the chemical structure.